# Can't forward traffic from eth to TUN/TAP

Tags: iptables, vpn, tunneling, forwarding

I'm trying to forward traffic from a physical interface `enp5s0` to a virtual one `tun0`. The goal is to make `tun0` receive essentially all packets from `enp5s0`.

First, I enable forwarding with a command

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then I create `tun0` by running

```
sudo ip tuntap add dev tun0 mod tun
```

I assign it IP-address and turn the device on:

```
sudo ifconfig tun0 10.1.8.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 promisc up
```

I want to make all packets go from `enp5s0` to `tun0`, so I have to use *iptables*. I need to make a rule that allows forwarding from `enp5s0` to `tun0`, so the command is

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface tun0 --out-interface enp5s0 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I enable NAT by running

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface enp5s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

*tcpdump* shows no traffic on `tun0`.

Also, I tried almost the same thing, but using TAP device. I created a bridge with `brctl`, added `tap0` and `enp5s0`, but no packets were received by `tap0` and everything was ok with `enp5s0`. Nothing like `default gw 10.1.8.5` works in TUN case. Where is a mistake?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to capture all `enp5s0` traffic on `tun0`. Every packet received by `enp5s0` `should be forwarded to `tun0`

Answer (score 3):

Your in and out interfaces are reversed in the iptables command.

They should be:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface enp5s0 --out-interface tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

and:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I've tried yours and `tcpdump -i tun0` is still empty

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I have used these commands to set up a vpn over a tun device (which is why I know about the in/out order), however you would normally have something on the other side of the tun0 interface - either the other end of the vpn or a local application that opens the device. Just having the tun0 device with an ip address doesn't mean that traffic will flow - its like having an ethernet port with the cable unplugged. This might be useful: http://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces/

Comment: Thanks for a link. The goal is to capture all `enp5s0` traffic on `tun0`. I have a program that reads packets from `tun0`, spoofs them and send them back on wire. I've tried `ping` and `traceroute` to test the connection, and the thing is that there are some records on packet going though PREROUTE chain and that's all, packets are not being  forwarded even if I make a rule and enable forwarding.

Comment: It's ok to ping tun endpoint from the forwarding host(the tun gateway). But it does not work on the other hosts -- IP packets are forwarded to the (gateway) tun device without NAT, so the endpoint won't be able to response to the 'correct' source IP. So the below rule saved my day: `udo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to make the packets WANT to go to that interface.
This can be done either by routing or iptables.

First test: from your own host, ping something like `10.1.8.57`.  It should show up in your tcpdump.  If it doesn't, nothing else will ever work. so fix it.

Start with routing.
On the host declare a network on the other end of tun0, which I believe you've made `10.1.8.0/24`.  Put an entry for that on a host on the other end of the enp5s0 link, routing to your host.  From that host, ping something like `10.1.8.57`.  This should show up in your tcpdump.

On to iptables.  In this case, I think what you want is to take packets normally traveling to your host, and forward them on to the TUN interface.  The trick for this is a DNAT rule.  I think something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --in-interface enp5s0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.8.57
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --in-interface enp5s0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.8.57
```

(Actually, this target is valid on PREROUTING and OUTPUT, and I apparently put it on both when I used it.  I'm not sure if you need both, or just one, or if they do different cases.)
For early testing, I recommend addition additional restrictions on what is rerouted, like adding `-p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000` and then trying to connect to port 5000.  If you aren't careful, you could block yourself out of the machine altogether.